# Two identical pages, jQuery leanmodal works only in one

Tags: javascript, jquery

By the code alone, the scripts and libraries loaded in two pages are identical, the same template used, just slight difference in main content, but leanmodal works only while on the index page, but NOT in any other page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
 <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal">Login/Register</a>


 <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
<header class="popupHeader">
  <span class="header_title">site.lt</span>

</header>

<section class="popupBody">
  <!-- Social Login -->
  <div class="social_login">
    <div class="">
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#modal_trigger, #add_ad").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

  $(function(){
    // Calling Login Form
    $("#login_form").click(function(){
      $(".social_login").hide();
      $(".user_login").show();
      $(".password_reset").hide();
      return false;
    });
```

You can try it here (click "Prisijungti/Užsiregistruoti" in the top right corner) http://www.bilietukai.lt . Can't see anything relevant in console either, well at least I can not see it, because I'm more a PHP guy currently and not good enough in JS/jQuery yet.

Comment: Looks like you're loading jquery.leanModal.min.js incorrectly on the other pages. Are you sure your paths are correct?

Comment: The thing is - I'm using exactly the same header with all the script and paths. I can see only difference is that there is something after .lt extension, I mean like .lt/muzika or other adress, not just homepage/main domain. Maybe that has something to do/somehow interferes with how modal is being initiated. Can't wrap my head around this..

Comment: You're using relative paths to load them though. So on the home page (http://www.bilietukai.lt/) the file "js/jquery.leanModal.min.js" resolves to http://www.bilietukai.lt/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js. On the Muzika page (http://www.bilietukai.lt/Muzika/) the same file resolves to "http://www.bilietukai.lt/Muzika//js/jquery.leanModal.min.js", which isn't where the file is. I think making it an absolute path will help, so "/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"

Comment: Genius! It just shows how sometimes we can miss something so simple, I've literally spent several hours just trying to figure this out and it was pretty much in front of me, but I looked for more complicated reasons. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alex Taker found the issue, the relative path of js script. So obvious I just lost the forest for the trees when looking for the problem.